# Help redraw this correlation table to fit my pdf page and to be readable

Tags: tables, rotating, pdfpages

```
%\begin{table}[htbp]
\small
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
      \begin{tabular}{|l|p{4.855em}|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{NIM (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{GDP  (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{ROE} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{ROA} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{INFLTN} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{FDI} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{BCBD (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{DBACBA (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{CBAGDP (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{DBAGDP (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{FDGDP (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{LISTCO\_PC} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{LL\_USD} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{XREGME} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{XREGCON} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{OVERHEAD (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{LLGDP (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{STMKCAP (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{STVALT\_D (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{STTURN\_R (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{NRBLOAN (\%)} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{21}[41]{*}{Pearson Correlation}} & NIM (\%) & 1.000 & .068  & .466  & .556  & .325  & -.030 & -.322 & -.418 & .304  & -.280 & -.329 & -.312 & -.081 & -.329 & .470  & .593  & -.386 & -.182 & -.114 & .102  & .016 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & GDP  (\%) & .068  & 1.000 & -.015 & .111  & .044  & -.089 & -.079 & .013  & -.036 & .006  & -.031 & .002  & .103  & -.240 & .329  & .143  & -.045 & -.454 & -.461 & .037  & -.234 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & ROE   & .466  & -.015 & 1.000 & .810  & .097  & .234  & -.162 & .139  & -.095 & -.067 & .058  & .064  & -.159 & .221  & -.068 & -.164 & .018  & .070  & .074  & -.026 & .087 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & ROA   & .556  & .111  & .810  & 1.000 & .246  & -.034 & -.153 & .034  & -.054 & -.048 & -.018 & -.058 & -.072 & .018  & .222  & -.014 & -.059 & -.044 & -.041 & -.053 & -.010 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & INFLTN & .325  & .044  & .097  & .246  & 1.000 & -.231 & -.146 & -.335 & .321  & -.065 & -.142 & -.115 & -.012 & -.292 & .308  & .048  & -.134 & -.081 & -.051 & .091  & -.072 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & FDI   & -.030 & -.089 & .234  & -.034 & -.231 & 1.000 & -.172 & -.049 & .131  & -.165 & .066  & .105  & -.169 & .315  & -.294 & .010  & -.021 & .271  & .259  & -.029 & -.069 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & BCBD (\%) & -.322 & -.079 & -.162 & -.153 & -.146 & -.172 & 1.000 & .375  & -.334 & .394  & .179  & .208  & .158  & .206  & -.522 & -.262 & .254  & .079  & .071  & .042  & .391 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & DBACBA (\%) & -.418 & .013  & .139  & .034  & -.335 & -.049 & .375  & 1.000 & -.884 & .364  & .453  & .298  & .318  & .268  & -.248 & -.569 & .440  & .105  & .083  & .150  & -.139 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & CBAGDP (\%) & .304  & -.036 & -.095 & -.054 & .321  & .131  & -.334 & -.884 & 1.000 & -.203 & -.266 & -.174 & -.238 & -.295 & .221  & .513  & -.269 & -.086 & -.069 & -.106 & .075 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & DBAGDP (\%) & -.280 & .006  & -.067 & -.048 & -.065 & -.165 & .394  & .364  & -.203 & 1.000 & .900  & .794  & .045  & -.218 & -.247 & -.393 & .929  & .087  & .030  & -.026 & .155 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & FDGDP (\%) & -.329 & -.031 & .058  & -.018 & -.142 & .066  & .179  & .453  & -.266 & .900  & 1.000 & .819  & -.039 & -.036 & -.270 & -.463 & .974  & .134  & .065  & -.022 & .040 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & LISTCO\_PC & -.312 & .002  & .064  & -.058 & -.115 & .105  & .208  & .298  & -.174 & .794  & .819  & 1.000 & -.074 & .105  & -.451 & -.419 & .806  & .121  & .064  & .015  & .042 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & LL\_USD & -.081 & .103  & -.159 & -.072 & -.012 & -.169 & .158  & .318  & -.238 & .045  & -.039 & -.074 & 1.000 & -.301 & .204  & -.108 & -.086 & -.034 & -.016 & .060  & -.303 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & XREGME & -.329 & -.240 & .221  & .018  & -.292 & .315  & .206  & .268  & -.295 & -.218 & -.036 & .105  & -.301 & 1.000 & -.706 & -.255 & -.018 & .177  & .151  & .034  & .220 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & XREGCON & .470  & .329  & -.068 & .222  & .308  & -.294 & -.522 & -.248 & .221  & -.247 & -.270 & -.451 & .204  & -.706 & 1.000 & .407  & -.342 & -.345 & -.308 & .013  & -.489 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & OVERHEAD (\%) & .593  & .143  & -.164 & -.014 & .048  & .010  & -.262 & -.569 & .513  & -.393 & -.463 & -.419 & -.108 & -.255 & .407  & 1.000 & -.495 & -.311 & -.254 & .125  & -.060 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & LLGDP (\%) & -.386 & -.045 & .018  & -.059 & -.134 & -.021 & .254  & .440  & -.269 & .929  & .974  & .806  & -.086 & -.018 & -.342 & -.495 & 1.000 & .110  & .035  & -.052 & .145 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & STMKCAP (\%) & -.182 & -.454 & .070  & -.044 & -.081 & .271  & .079  & .105  & -.086 & .087  & .134  & .121  & -.034 & .177  & -.345 & -.311 & .110  & 1.000 & .988  & -.023 & .162 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & STVALT\_D (\%) & -.114 & -.461 & .074  & -.041 & -.051 & .259  & .071  & .083  & -.069 & .030  & .065  & .064  & -.016 & .151  & -.308 & -.254 & .035  & .988  & 1.000 & .083  & .168 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & STTURN\_R (\%) & .102  & .037  & -.026 & -.053 & .091  & -.029 & .042  & .150  & -.106 & -.026 & -.022 & .015  & .060  & .034  & .013  & .125  & -.052 & -.023 & .083  & 1.000 & .051 \\
\cmidrule{2-2}          & NRBLOAN (\%) & .016  & -.234 & .087  & -.010 & -.072 & -.069 & .391  & -.139 & .075  & .155  & .040  & .042  & -.303 & .220  & -.489 & -.060 & .145  & .162  & .168  & .051  & 1.000 \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
%\end{table}%
```

Comment: Well, _what_ is your page size? The table looks scary, have you tried `pdflscape` for rotating?

Comment: we can't help you if you not provide any information about your document preamble. please be so kind and extend your code snippet to complete but small document beginning with `\documentclass[...]{...}`, followed with package which determine page layout and others packages relevant for your table, and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Oleg I have tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a 21x21 correlation table look "good" is always going to be a serious artistic challenge. (Aside: Do you have any reason to believe that your readers will care about being shown the full correlation table? Would they be just as well, or even better, off if you just report the 2 or 3 correlations that really matter?)

Some suggestions:

- To conserve a serious amount of scarce horizontal space, omit the entire first column, and place the string "Pearson Correlation" in the argument of `\caption`.
- Load the `sidewaystable` package and encase the entire table in a `sidewaystable` environment. I trust you can guess what the `sidewaystable` environment does.
- Simplify the header cells drastically. Instead of stating the variable names, just number the columns as (1), (2), etc. There just isn't enough space to list the variable names again. After all, you're already listing the variable names in the firs column.
- Get rid of all 23 [!] vertical lines -- you'd be surprised how much space 23 lines can take up -- and of 20 of the 23 horizontal lines. Load the `booktabs` package and use `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` to draw the 3 remaining horizontal lines. Optional: Insert `\addlinespace` directives after every 5th row.
- Use a `tabular*` environment and set its overall width to `\textwidth`.
- Use math mode for the data columns, to ensure that the `-` symbols get typeset as math-minus symbols rather than as text-mode "dash" symbols
- Even with all of these adjustments, you'll still need to switch the font size to either `\footnotesize` or even `\scriptsize`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page size parameters appropriately
\usepackage{booktabs,rotating,array,caption}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}} % right-aligned, math mode

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,font=footnotesize}
\caption{Pearson Correlations} \label{tab:addlabel}
\footnotesize % or even "\scriptsize", if necessary

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional; for a more open "look"

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out max. intercol. whitespace
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{21}{R} }
\toprule
&  (1) &  (2) &  (3) &  (4) &  (5) &  (6) &  (7) &  (8) &  (9) & (10)
& (11) & (12) & (13) & (14) & (15) & (16) & (17) & (18) & (19) & (20) & (21) \\
\midrule
(1) NIM (\%) & 1.000 & .068  & .466  & .556  & .325  & -.030 & -.322 & -.418 & .304  & -.280 & -.329 & -.312 & -.081 & -.329 & .470  & .593  & -.386 & -.182 & -.114 & .102  & .016 \\
(2) GDP  (\%) & .068  & 1.000 & -.015 & .111  & .044  & -.089 & -.079 & .013  & -.036 & .006  & -.031 & .002  & .103  & -.240 & .329  & .143  & -.045 & -.454 & -.461 & .037  & -.234 \\
(3) ROE   & .466  & -.015 & 1.000 & .810  & .097  & .234  & -.162 & .139  & -.095 & -.067 & .058  & .064  & -.159 & .221  & -.068 & -.164 & .018  & .070  & .074  & -.026 & .087 \\
(4) ROA   & .556  & .111  & .810  & 1.000 & .246  & -.034 & -.153 & .034  & -.054 & -.048 & -.018 & -.058 & -.072 & .018  & .222  & -.014 & -.059 & -.044 & -.041 & -.053 & -.010 \\
(5) INFLTN & .325  & .044  & .097  & .246  & 1.000 & -.231 & -.146 & -.335 & .321  & -.065 & -.142 & -.115 & -.012 & -.292 & .308  & .048  & -.134 & -.081 & -.051 & .091  & -.072 \\
\addlinespace
(6) FDI   & -.030 & -.089 & .234  & -.034 & -.231 & 1.000 & -.172 & -.049 & .131  & -.165 & .066  & .105  & -.169 & .315  & -.294 & .010  & -.021 & .271  & .259  & -.029 & -.069 \\
(7) BCBD (\%) & -.322 & -.079 & -.162 & -.153 & -.146 & -.172 & 1.000 & .375  & -.334 & .394  & .179  & .208  & .158  & .206  & -.522 & -.262 & .254  & .079  & .071  & .042  & .391 \\
(8) DBACBA (\%) & -.418 & .013  & .139  & .034  & -.335 & -.049 & .375  & 1.000 & -.884 & .364  & .453  & .298  & .318  & .268  & -.248 & -.569 & .440  & .105  & .083  & .150  & -.139 \\
(9) CBAGDP (\%) & .304  & -.036 & -.095 & -.054 & .321  & .131  & -.334 & -.884 & 1.000 & -.203 & -.266 & -.174 & -.238 & -.295 & .221  & .513  & -.269 & -.086 & -.069 & -.106 & .075 \\
(10) DBAGDP (\%) & -.280 & .006  & -.067 & -.048 & -.065 & -.165 & .394  & .364  & -.203 & 1.000 & .900  & .794  & .045  & -.218 & -.247 & -.393 & .929  & .087  & .030  & -.026 & .155 \\
\addlinespace
(11) FDGDP (\%) & -.329 & -.031 & .058  & -.018 & -.142 & .066  & .179  & .453  & -.266 & .900  & 1.000 & .819  & -.039 & -.036 & -.270 & -.463 & .974  & .134  & .065  & -.022 & .040 \\
(12) LISTCO\_PC & -.312 & .002  & .064  & -.058 & -.115 & .105  & .208  & .298  & -.174 & .794  & .819  & 1.000 & -.074 & .105  & -.451 & -.419 & .806  & .121  & .064  & .015  & .042 \\
(13) LL\_USD & -.081 & .103  & -.159 & -.072 & -.012 & -.169 & .158  & .318  & -.238 & .045  & -.039 & -.074 & 1.000 & -.301 & .204  & -.108 & -.086 & -.034 & -.016 & .060  & -.303 \\
(14) XREGME & -.329 & -.240 & .221  & .018  & -.292 & .315  & .206  & .268  & -.295 & -.218 & -.036 & .105  & -.301 & 1.000 & -.706 & -.255 & -.018 & .177  & .151  & .034  & .220 \\
(15) XREGCON & .470  & .329  & -.068 & .222  & .308  & -.294 & -.522 & -.248 & .221  & -.247 & -.270 & -.451 & .204  & -.706 & 1.000 & .407  & -.342 & -.345 & -.308 & .013  & -.489 \\
\addlinespace
(16) OVERHEAD (\%) & .593  & .143  & -.164 & -.014 & .048  & .010  & -.262 & -.569 & .513  & -.393 & -.463 & -.419 & -.108 & -.255 & .407  & 1.000 & -.495 & -.311 & -.254 & .125  & -.060 \\
(17) LLGDP (\%) & -.386 & -.045 & .018  & -.059 & -.134 & -.021 & .254  & .440  & -.269 & .929  & .974  & .806  & -.086 & -.018 & -.342 & -.495 & 1.000 & .110  & .035  & -.052 & .145 \\
(18) STMKCAP (\%) & -.182 & -.454 & .070  & -.044 & -.081 & .271  & .079  & .105  & -.086 & .087  & .134  & .121  & -.034 & .177  & -.345 & -.311 & .110  & 1.000 & .988  & -.023 & .162 \\
(19) STVALT\_D (\%) & -.114 & -.461 & .074  & -.041 & -.051 & .259  & .071  & .083  & -.069 & .030  & .065  & .064  & -.016 & .151  & -.308 & -.254 & .035  & .988  & 1.000 & .083  & .168 \\
(20) STTURN\_R (\%) & .102  & .037  & -.026 & -.053 & .091  & -.029 & .042  & .150  & -.106 & -.026 & -.022 & .015  & .060  & .034  & .013  & .125  & -.052 & -.023 & .083  & 1.000 & .051 \\
(21) NRBLOAN (\%) & .016  & -.234 & .087  & -.010 & -.072 & -.069 & .391  & -.139 & .075  & .155  & .040  & .042  & -.303 & .220  & -.489 & -.060 & .145  & .162  & .168  & .051  & 1.000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for this nice lecture on how to work with long tables.

Comment: @Sigur - Many thanks for this very kind compliment! :-)

Comment: @Mico, it's my pleasure. By the way, instead of `\textwidth`, is it possible to let it be computed automatically according to table contents? (maybe some `{*}`)

Comment: @Sigur - In my experience (which includes having served once as the editor of a conference proceedings volume, naturally done using LaTeX, when I had the pleasure of working with a professional book designer), once a table's natural width exceeds 85% or 90% of `\textwidth`, it is preferable to set its width to `\textwidth` (and to use `tabularx` or `tabular*` to do so). This is especially the case if the document contains lots of tables, as then having to read lots of tables, which all have slightly varying widths, all a bit less than `\textwidth`, quickly becomes a serious distraction.

Comment: My table contains 9 cols and around 60% of `\textwidth`. I am using `tabularx` because of some `S` format. So if the width of table is too wide, the last col looks ugly since the rule goes too far on the right.

Comment: @Sigur - Feel free to post to your table to this site -- and ask specifically for advice on how to automate the choice of the first argument in `tabularx` and `tabular*` environments?

Comment: @Mico, I was trying to learn first but after hours I start to believe that I should ask. As an algebraic topologist I never needed complex tables, but now I need some.... lol