# Fitting a table that contains a 9x9 correlation matrix inside the text block

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to locate the table in the picture in the exact center. right now, it is protrudes to the right and looks ugly. This is the code I have:

```
\scalebox{0.75}{
\begin{center}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c c c c c c c c||} 
 \hline
  & SHSZ300 & RGUSHS & SPTRHLTH & MVGDXJTR & SX6R & GDLECFEF & NDELCHF & 
SXXR & SPTRINFT \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
SHSZ300&1.0000&0.1256&0.1231&0.1806&0.1800&0.4097&0.5796&0.2387&0.2593\\ 
 \hline
RGUSHS&0.1256&1.0000&0.7845&0.1667&0.3758&0.5186&0.3488&0.5881&0.5926\\
 \hline
SPTRHLTH&0.1231&0.7845&1.0000&0.1229&0.5322&0.6021&0.4604&0.6867&0.6586\\
 \hline
MVGDXJTR&0.1806&0.1667&0.1229&1.0000&0.0734&0.1163&0.3502&0.1841&0.1900\\
 \hline
SX6R&0.1800&0.3758&0.5322&0.0734&1.0000&0.5312&0.3054&0.7212&0.5611\\
 \hline
GDLECFEF&0.4097&0.5186&0.6021&0.1163&0.5312&1.0000&0.7493&0.7267&0.6943\\
 \hline
NDELCHF&0.5796&0.3488&0.4604&0.3502&0.3054&0.7493&1.0000&0.5453&0.5386\\
 \hline
SXXR&0.2387&0.5881&0.6867&0.1841&0.7212&0.7267&0.5453&1.0000&0.7182\\
 \hline
SPTRINFT&0.2593&0.5926&0.6586&0.1900&0.5611&0.6943&0.5386&0.7182&1.0000\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}
```

[image]

How do I possibly modify the code so that the table is exactly centered?

Comment: It is not centered because its width is much bigger than text width.

Comment: @Sigur Hi Siguar. Thank you very much for your reply. So what should I do? should I decrease the text width?

Comment: If you use `\begin{center}` there is no need for `\centering`.

Comment: @Skillmon I see. But neither actually centers the table.. As Sigur says it may be the problem of the width and text width size.. what am I supposed to do?

Comment: To force it to be centred without decreasing its width you could use `\makebox[0pt][c]{<your table>}` inside the `center` environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Or you could use `\resizebox` instead of `\scalebox` to resize it to fit the text width (but I won't do so personally).

Comment: neither `\begin{center}` nor `\centering` can work inside `\scalebox` `\scalebox` is a horzontal box like `\mbox`  in which vertical mode constructs have no effect.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you very much for your reply. So for the <your table>, what part of my code should I insert in?

Comment: The `tabular` environment and its contents. But be aware of @DavidCarlisle's comment.

Comment: just remove the `\scalebox` (scaling tables is evil anyway:-)  and the `\centering` then use `\begin{center}\small`  (or `\footnotesize` or `\tiny` or whatever size is needed so it fits on your page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi David.
So I removed the \scalebox and \centering as you said. it is still not centered...... omg LaTeX is pain in the ass

Comment: That's not LaTeX's fault. As @Sigur stated, your table is too wide. It is therefore not centred correctly. To resolve that, either change its size by using a smaller font (`\small` or the like) or by making the underlying system believe it is of zero width with `\makebox[0pt][c]{\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}}`.

Comment: did you make it smaller like  said with `\tiny` for example. but don't blame latex, it just does what you ask it to do. If you ask it to put a wide table in a narrow page, the output does not look good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i would redesign your table on the following way:

- exploit fact, that row headers and column headers are the same
- use `tabular*` for table environment
- set `tabsep` to take available space between columns
- not use vertical lines
- not use `\scalebox`
- for horizontal lines empoy `booktabs` package

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}%[htb]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                l
                           *{9}{c}
                            }
    \toprule
                & (1)   & (2)   & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) & (9) \\
    \midrule
(1): SHSZ300    &1.0000 &0.1256 &0.1231&0.1806&0.1800&0.4097&0.5796&0.2387&0.2593\\
(2): RGUSHS     &0.1256 &1.0000 &0.7845&0.1667&0.3758&0.5186&0.3488&0.5881&0.5926\\
(3): SPTRHLTH   &0.1231 &0.7845 &1.0000&0.1229&0.5322&0.6021&0.4604&0.6867&0.6586\\
    \addlinespace
(4): MVGDXJTR   &0.1806 &0.1667 &0.1229&1.0000&0.0734&0.1163&0.3502&0.1841&0.1900\\
(5): SX6R       &0.1800 &0.3758 &0.5322&0.0734&1.0000&0.5312&0.3054&0.7212&0.5611\\
(6): GDLECFEF   &0.4097 &0.5186 &0.6021&0.1163&0.5312&1.0000&0.7493&0.7267&0.6943\\
    \addlinespace
(7): NDELCHF    &0.5796 &0.3488 &0.4604&0.3502&0.3054&0.7493&1.0000&0.5453&0.5386\\
(8): SXXR       &0.2387 &0.5881 &0.6867&0.1841&0.7212&0.7267&0.5453&1.0000&0.7182\\
(9): SPTRINFT   &0.2593 &0.5926 &0.6586&0.1900&0.5611&0.6943&0.5386&0.7182&1.0000\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

*note*: since page layout of your document is not know, i assume that page is `A4` with borders as are default determined by `geometry` package. if text width is smaller, than might you need to reduce font size to `\small` or `footnotesize`.

Comment: yes, since it is in `table` ... it is removed now

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation on [@Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416551/5001) (and also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415302/5001)) that goes further in reducing visual clutter: It employs the `siunitx` package to display only 3 significant digits for all correlations. I think you'll be doing your readers a big favor by applying such a simplification.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\sisetup{round-mode      = places,
         round-precision = 3,
         table-format    = 1.3}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{9}{S} }
\toprule
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} & {(8)} & {(9)} \\
\midrule
(1) SHSZ300 & 1.0000 & 0.1256 & 0.1231& 0.1806& 0.1800& 0.4097& 0.5796& 0.2387& 0.2593\\
(2) RGUSHS  & 0.1256 & 1.0000 & 0.7845& 0.1667& 0.3758& 0.5186& 0.3488& 0.5881& 0.5926\\
(3) SPTRHLTH& 0.1231 & 0.7845 & 1.0000& 0.1229& 0.5322& 0.6021& 0.4604& 0.6867& 0.6586\\
\addlinespace
(4) MVGDXJTR& 0.1806 & 0.1667 & 0.1229& 1.0000& 0.0734& 0.1163& 0.3502& 0.1841& 0.1900\\
(5) SX6R    & 0.1800 & 0.3758 & 0.5322& 0.0734& 1.0000& 0.5312& 0.3054& 0.7212& 0.5611\\
(6) GDLECFEF& 0.4097 & 0.5186 & 0.6021& 0.1163& 0.5312& 1.0000& 0.7493& 0.7267& 0.6943\\
\addlinespace
(7) NDELCHF & 0.5796 & 0.3488 & 0.4604& 0.3502& 0.3054& 0.7493& 1.0000& 0.5453& 0.5386\\
(8) SXXR    & 0.2387 & 0.5881 & 0.6867& 0.1841& 0.7212& 0.7267& 0.5453& 1.0000& 0.7182\\
(9) SPTRINFT& 0.2593 & 0.5926 & 0.6586& 0.1900& 0.5611& 0.6943& 0.5386& 0.7182& 1.0000\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `\small` font size, reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` and using  multiline column heads  where necessary with the `\makecell` or `\thead` command are the usual tools to make a table fit the page width. In addition, I loaded `hhline` to hacve neater intersections of vertical and horizontal rules:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
    \usepackage{makecell, hhline}

    \begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
 \centering\small
 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
 \begin{tabular}{||*{10}{c}||}
 \hline
  & SHSZ300 & RGUSHS & \makecell{SPTRH\\LTH} & \makecell{MVGDXJ\\TR} & SX6R & \makecell{GDLECF\\EF} & \makecell{NDELC\\HF} &
SXXR & \makecell{SPTRIN\\FT} \\ [0.5ex]
 \hhline{}
SHSZ300&1.0000&0.1256&0.1231&0.1806&0.1800&0.4097&0.5796&0.2387&0.2593\\
 \hhline{||*{10}{=}||}
RGUSHS&0.1256&1.0000&0.7845&0.1667&0.3758&0.5186&0.3488&0.5881&0.5926\\
 \hhline{||*{10}{=}||}
SPTRHLTH&0.1231&0.7845&1.0000&0.1229&0.5322&0.6021&0.4604&0.6867&0.6586\\
 \hhline{||*{10}{=}||}
MVGDXJTR&0.1806&0.1667&0.1229&1.0000&0.0734&0.1163&0.3502&0.1841&0.1900\\
 \hhline{||*{10}{=}||}
SX6R&0.1800&0.3758&0.5322&0.0734&1.0000&0.5312&0.3054&0.7212&0.5611\\
 \hhline{||*{10}{=}||}
GDLECFEF&0.4097&0.5186&0.6021&0.1163&0.5312&1.0000&0.7493&0.7267&0.6943\\
 \hhline{||*{10}{=}||}
NDELCHF&0.5796&0.3488&0.4604&0.3502&0.3054&0.7493&1.0000&0.5453&0.5386\\
 \hhline{||*{10}{=}||}
SXXR&0.2387&0.5881&0.6867&0.1841&0.7212&0.7267&0.5453&1.0000&0.7182\\
 \hhline{||*{10}{=}||}
SPTRINFT&0.2593&0.5926&0.6586&0.1900&0.5611&0.6943&0.5386&0.7182&1.0000\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]